# Unable to See Files on Drive On Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ntfs

Drive is 1T external USB SSD formatted to NTFS (by Ubuntu). (Dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 15.04) Works great on Linux. But in Windows 7 it shows up as empty. No errors. dir /a shows just two files, a system file and a trashcan file. The size shows up as empty. I can even create a folder and view it, so it acts like a perfectly good empty drive.
When I boot back to Ubuntu I cannot see the folder I created in Windows, but I can again see the 190G contents I expect. fsck and chkdsk report no errors.
I had to format in Ubuntu because Ubuntu would not mount if formatted in either NTFS or exFAT by Windows.

Comment: Try formatting it to fat

Comment: Windows 7 offers only NTFS and exFAT as choices.

Answer (score 0):

show checked "Show hidden files and folders", as well as unchecked "Hide extensions for known files types" and "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" in the 
    **Tools / Folder Options / View Tab** 
I found all my files in one of the folders I wasn't seeing before. There were several folders that seemed to have been generated as a result of this hard drive issue, and one of them contained all my files.

visit the link:http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/

Comment: If I show everything all I get are the two system files, like the trash can. It appears that Windows 7 only partially understands the Ubuntu version of NTFS.